# Cannot access some members of LineRenderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties, line, renderer

I have a line renderer component on a prefab, and would like to be able to add positions to this line renderer in script.

I thought I would be able to simply append `LineRenderer.positionCount` to add a point to the list, which the [unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-positionCount.html) appears to suggest. I've also seen this suggested when I've tried to search for a solution.

However, when I try this I get a compile error, saying that `positionCount` doesn't exist:

```
'LineRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'positionCount' and no extension method 'positionCount' accepting a first argument of type 'LineRenderer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The same is true if I try to use `LineRenderer.GetPositions()` or even if I try to just access `LineRenderer.positions` directly, they don't appear to exist.

As you can see hear these properties and methods don't appear in Visual Studio when I try to access them. All that's visible when searching `position` are `SetPosition()` and `SetPositions()`.

[image: No Properties :(]

So what am I doing wrong here, and how do I access these properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can see is **you may be using an *ancient* version of Unity**:

Before Unity 5.5, the only members of `LineRenderer` containing "position" in their name are `SetPosition` and `SetPositions`, see the [legacy doc of 5.4](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html).

Although I would find it surprising, if you were to be on such a version, it would be in your best interest to upgrade *asap as possible.*

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea the version I was using wasn’t up to date, but everything works fine now.